# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Equal to MIN applied to multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have this list of numbers. I applied a custom number format to it. It's just colon and dot(not decimal point). My goal is to highlight the lowest number there. I'm convinced that my idea of "Is equal to min(A1:A19)" is correct but the result... Any idea why is it highlighting 4 cells and how can I reach my goal some other way?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I first edited [player0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126807) in order to add some explanation for this issue, but since the edit was rolled back, I'm posting this answer for documentation purposes.

#### Issue:

The conditional formatting is highlighting the minimum value starting from current row, not from `A1`. For example, `A10` is the minimum value in the range `A10:A19`, so it gets highlighted.

#### Solution:

Add the `$` operator to the formula:

```
=MIN(A$1:A19)
```

Or set `Format cells` as `Custom formula is` and set your formula to:

```
=A1=MIN(A$1:A19)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=MIN(A$1:A19)
```

or: like this and set it as custom formula:

```
=A1=MIN(A$1:A19)
```